# Flagged question count is wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, flag-queue

I have a "3" currently in the number of flagged posts:

[image]

However, when I click on the number, the list is empty. On the side-bar of the list, I can see this here:

[image]

But again, on any of the linked lists, nothing is to be found.

Is this a "travel"-issue? Or site-wide? Is this only on my account or do others have the same issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a long-standing caching bug - in the old days, there were lots and lots of items in the /tools/flagged queue, and we hid items you had already flagged (or taken action on).

Now, most posts that would have been shown in /tools/flagged are sent straight to various review queues, so /tools/flagged stays a bit lean.

I'm just going to show the items you have flagged in a grayed out (or semi-opaque) styling, so you can see what you've already acted upon, and I don't have to make some crazy, per-user caching structure that stays in sync with flags (especially since we want to remove /tools/flagged in favor of review queues).

MEGA EDIT

So, next build will push out the above changes; here's a screenshot illustrating them:

[image]

Gone is the random sorting of /tools/flagged - it will now be sorted the same as the mod queue, which is by most flagged post, then oldest flag.  Also, if you've already flagged a post in the /tools/flagged queue, it will be sorted to the end of the list and grayed out, with some explanation of why you can no longer interact with it.

Thank you for being the straw that broke this camel's back and made me fix this bug :)

Comment: +1 +1 +1 - This has been reported countless times.  Great solution Jared!

Comment: Although, I have to say I'll really miss /tools/flagged *(didn't see that part of your message at first)*. It stays true to that whole "we don't run Stack Overflow, you do" message, especially for the promise of 10k access to moderator tools. It makes us feel more empowered to help lead the community...