# Moderator tools are allowing me to attempt to flag a post I've already flagged

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, 10k-tools

On History.stackExchange.com I flagged a question as *very low quality* about an hour ago, and also voted to close it.

Someone else just repeated the same flag, so now I have a little yellow flag beside the Review button, which takes me to the Tools -> Flags page and asks me to pass judgement on the raised flags. However, as I have already both flagged the question and voted to close it, I am unable to take further action.

I believe this is a bug, which may only manifest on smaller beta sites.

It gives me both buttons and allows me to use them - but of course going further would undo my previous action. I am a trusted user on history.stackexchange.com as of a few days ago.

Comment: Does it give you action buttons for the post, that you just can't use?

Comment: No, it gives me both buttons and allows me to use them - but of course going further would undo my previous action.

Comment: Is this the 10K tools?

Comment: @hichris123 It appears so, though they can be made usable at lower reputations on beta sites.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I realise that, I just don't know what to call it otherwise. The 10K tools on launched sites and the whateverK tools on beta's is a little wordy, don't you think? :)

Comment: I have full moderator privilege on History.stackexchange.com, making me a Trusted User on that site. I only achieved that privilege level a few days ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug with assumptions built into that /tools/flagged queue.

You originally flagged the question as "Other... (needs mod attention)" and gave a custom reason - **these flags are only shown to diamond moderators**, so they aren't being loaded on that page.  This is why you can see flagging and closing controls on a question you've already taken action on.

I'll fix this so you'll be able to see you've already taken action, as shown in this answer: [Flagged question count is wrong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212285/flagged-question-count-is-wrong/212286#212286)

Comment: OK. I don't really follow you completely, but trust that you do.

Comment: What's happening is that when you load /tools/flagged, the server doesn't load every type of flag on the posts, only flags that you can see.  So, when rendering that page, the server is unaware of your "Other..." flag (because you can't see them, only diamond mods), and assumes you've not flagged at all.