# Flagged a question/answer, got to review the flag

Tags: bug, flags, 10k-tools

Recently (on Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange) I got the privilege to review flags. I had flagged an answer (or question, I don't remember), and got to review my own flag request.

Comment: This is in `/tools`, right?

Comment: Your description of the issue is extremely vague, but I believe [Moderator tools are allowing me to attempt to flag a post I've already flagged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212535/moderator-tools-are-allowing-me-to-attempt-to-flag-a-post-ive-already-flagged?rq=1) is the same issue, although that one is marked as [tag:status-completed] so could be new.  Either way the 10K tools are going away so it likely won't get fixed.