# Review flag count is still wrong

Tags: bug, review, flags, top-bar

In "[Flagged question count is wrong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212285/flagged-question-count-is-wrong)" the bug that left review flags visible in the top-bar counter was supposedly fixed, but it's never actually been fixed for me. This is what I'm looking at today:

[image: Six flags showing]

My review queues are all empty though. Six is abnormally high, normally it sits (every day, all day) at 3. This is on [RPG.SE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/), where we get lots of flags but we have enough reviewers that the queues are usually dealt with super-quickly. The only time the flag count drops to zero-and-invisible is when I get to the queues first and clear them out myself. I don't know why it should make a difference whether it's me or someone else clearing them, but if I don't, it's that **[ 3 ]** shouting at me all day.

The review flag count has been useless for long enough that I just don't click it much. This is really counterproductive, especially for one of the top users of the site.

Why is the review count unrelated to the content of the review queues?

**Update:** This appears to be a symptom of using the **skip** button in a review queue. It seems like the number/flag doesn't clear when a review item is skipped, even though that dismisses the item and removes it from my queue.

If that's the case, skipping should either not remove it from the queue interface and the count/flag left working how it does now, or skipping should clear that item's count/flag and the queue left working how it does now.