# On some sites, the review number isn't accurate

Tags: discussion, review, top-bar

On some sites, such as Music Fans (beta), it shows me a number at the top:

[image: screen shot of Stack Exchange menu bar]

But when I click on it, there are no reviews available.  This also happens on Movies & TV.

Does this mean reviews exist that I don't have enough rep for?  Or is it a glitch?

Comment: This thing has bothered me for a long time. I was told it's cached. It happened when I reached 2k (aka 10k on grad sites). Before that, only suggested edits had that number, and they displayed that correctly.

Comment: On M&TV it's usually, like, 6 or something.  It's just weird.

Comment: Hehe! On chemistry, it's like showing 3 for each post needing review. It also once showed 14, when only one close vote was pending review.

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251659/what-does-the-number-next-to-the-review-link-in-the-top-bar-actually-mean (also contains links to other related topics)

Comment: It doesn't sound like the same question to me.  And that one never got an answer.  Mine is about what appears to be a caching issue, while that is about displaying one bit of info vs another.

Comment: Sounds closer to Jason's post.  But once you get 10K you get all review privileges, don't you?  Because I see it on M&TV too.

Comment: The review count is not always accurate due to possible caching and that it shows total, not remaining flags.

Comment: Those are likely Tag Wiki suggested edits, that require more reputation to review.