# Hide number of edits to review in the header when the user already reached the daily limit

Tags: discussion, review, feedback, header

I reached my daily limit many times for reviewing edits on Stack Overflow.

Yet, I always have the number of edits to review. And when clicking on it, it tells you that you can't review more; you reached daily limit. This annoyed me when I forgot that I already did.

[image: Edits to review]

I suggest when the daily limit is reached to either:

- Hide it
- Turn it to gray color, or any other non-attracting color.

Comment: That number is not ["personalized"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251698/158100).