# How do I refresh the review queue to clear non-existent reviews?

Tags: support, review

I'm a moderator at Robotics, and I have a persistent indicator for questions in my review queue, despite the fact that there aren't any.

I can open an incognito tab and log in, I can open in Internet Explorer, I hit F5 - nothing will get those numbers to go away. It's been 4 for a while now, but that number is prone to change on a seemingly random basis. It's frustrating for me because I tend to ignore it completely since it doesn't indicate correctly, and then posts go by without attention.

I posted this question on [our Meta](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1304/9720) a while back. Previously I could get the number to go away eventually by logging completely out and then back in, but that doesn't clear it any more.

Is there something else that I'm supposed to be doing? This problem isn't the end of the world, but it's the only nagging grievance I have about the site and I'd like to get it resolved.

Screencap:

[image: Robotics SE Review Queue]

### EDIT

Regarding the [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230802/337600) already asked, the only answer states,

> "[S]omeone needs to keep an eye on things to make sure **stuff is actually getting done**."

How do I know what "stuff" needs to get done when the number doesn't appear to mean anything?

> "If that number is high or growing, then there's a problem."

What is the problem? How do I know what to do? **What does the number *mean***?

That question links to a [third question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar) as related, where the OP says, "This should be something that you can get to 0 every day."

In comment to the accepted answer to *that* question, moderator Shog9 says,

> "this is *everything* in review, even stuff that you, personally, can't review. Super-expensive to personalize this - so the alternative is simply *not having an indicator*. Think of it as... A reminder to encourage your peers to review."

There's no built-in direct/private message system, so how exactly are we supposed to "encourage" our peers to review?

Further, I'm not just a super-user, I'm a *moderator*. It was frustrating when I had access to all of the tools, but now I'm a moderator and there's still stuff I'm not allowed to see?

So, to refine/distinguish this question and separate it from the others:

### What am I supposed to *do* about the review number when all of the queues are empty for me?

(This is really just a rephrasing of my original question - the only thing with a question mark, that says, "Is there something else that I'm supposed to be doing?")

Comment: They're not non-existent. You just can't see them. If I recall, it's by design. I'll see if I can find the post describing it as such.

Comment: @AlE. - I don't understand. If I'm not allowed to view them, why notify me that they exist at all? Looking forward to seeing some explanation (and really glad that I'm not crazy and/or it's a cache issue or something).

Comment: I'm also one of the the close voter and I just had this question in the reopen queue where I clicked leave closed. *What does the number mean?* It shows the number of pending reviews system wide for all users.   Suppose there is one review pending. The number wil show: 1. When a user reviews it, the review is still pending because it needs more votes to be completed. For the user the queue is empty because they have done that single review, the review indicator stil shows 1.

Comment: *What am I supposed to do about the review number when all of the queues are empty for me?* Nothing, you have to wait till other users complete their reviews in all queues. The only thing you could do is encourage users to do their chores. The fact that you are a mod might influence stuff but you have to ask in the TL about that.

Comment: Also see my answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251659/what-does-the-number-next-to-the-review-link-in-the-top-bar-actually-mean/251914#251914). side note: I use this [script](http://stackapps.com/questions/6869/review-stalker-reloaded-a-cross-site-dashboard-for-reviews) that actually shows me in the title if there are reviews for me available. I ignore the review indicator completely.