# "Posts Awaiting Review" value should not display if there are items I cannot review

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review

I recently proposed a tag wiki description and excerpt on a site where the review queue was completely empty.  After submitting the suggestions, I was alerted in the toolbar that there were two suggested edits for review.  Clicking into the queue showed that there were no items for me to review, since I can't review my own suggestions.

[image: Toolbar]

Review items which I cannot review should not appear in this toolbar.

Comment: Related: [Notification for reviews shows way too many](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230742/299342). It's by design.

Comment: Calculating that number is very expensive for a single user as it has to take into account passed actions, skips, already voted stuff, as explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251659/what-does-the-number-next-to-the-review-link-in-the-top-bar-actually-mean/251914#251914). As a feature request I see some merit in it but I rather have other stuff fixed. Maybe in 6 to 8 years...