# Remaining review count after suggesting a tag improvement

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

Today is not the first time I have seen a `1` icon in the remaining review count, but when I click on it, message says that there are no items in the queues.

Sorry for non-English site on the screenshot (I only have enough rep on ruSO).

> [image: empty queue]

I know that can be due to caching, and most times if I do refresh the page, the `1` icon disappears. But when I myself make a suggested edit to a tag's description I will see such `1` even when I do refresh a page many times. It can disappear and appear again, but it completely goes only when my suggested edit is approved or rejected.

So my thought here is some sort of weird bug. Need to dig more, though.

Comment: The count on top bar is what  all users see, it does not omit items you can't review. The review page itself, however, does omit those items, hence the different count.

Comment: @ShadowWizard hmm... dupe of the dupe?

Comment: There is a (declined) FR to change this: [“Posts Awaiting Review” value should not display if there are items I cannot review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283209/posts-awaiting-review-value-should-not-display-if-there-are-items-i-cannot-rev)

Comment: @Cai this FR completly explains my "bug" report. I upvoted it!

Comment: @alexolut edge case.... the dupe I voted for is **exact dupe**, while the actual answer (by Shog) is given in its own dupe. I know it creates a chain, but think it's fine, as closing directly as the root will be bit confusing, as the top bar is not mentioned in there at all.